# To create check box in symfony using widgets and also validate it?

Tags: php, symfony1

the code in symfony that i am using,

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
    'mobile'                       =>new sfWidgetFormInput(),
    'subscribetosms'               =>new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
));
```

i want to validate the checkbox, and also code to take values from check box

Comment: Please at least make an attempt to read the Symfony book before asking questions. This is an extremely basic question regarding symfony forms. Also, please learn how to format your posts on SO.

Comment: i am sorry, and thank u for ur comment, i will do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to validate form fields in symfony u need to set validators like this (assuming you are in a form class):

```
$this->setValidators(array(
      'mobile'          => new sfValidatorString(array(...)),
      'subscribetosms'  => new sfValidatorInteger(array(...))
    ));
```

Question is, what do you want to validate? If you want some kind of value send to your php script if the checkbox is selected you need to set this value in the widget.

```
new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(array('value_attribute_value'=>'your_value' )
```

Now you could configure your validator to validate this value (sfValidatorString for a string, of sfValidatorInteger for an integer).

To get the value in your action after the validation:

```
if ($this->form->isValid()) {
  $myValue = $this->form->getValue('subscribetosms');
}
```